# How to search and highlight multiple words inside cells in excel using macros?

Tags: vba, excel

I have paragraphs in each cell that I want to parse through to find specific words and then highlight them (not just the cell). It can be hard coded. I searched online and did not find anything that fixed the problem I am facing. Thank you so much.

Comment: So in a single cell, you have paragraphs of text - and in that paragraph, you want a specific word highlighted if found?  This will need VBA for sure, what have you tried so far that isn't working?  Instead of highlighting the word, what if you were just told whether the word is found or not?

Comment: `split` the cell by space, loop through array and check against your key words as you drop each back into cell, if matches, color it before drop?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. I would use regular expressions, and the characters property of the range object.  By the way, this is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot highlight individual words even manually. You could, however, change an individual word's font color.

According to this [link](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/146908-Highlighting-one-word-in-a-cell), you can try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Highlight()

    Dim rCell    As Range
    Dim zFind    As String
    Dim lFindLen As Long

    zFind = "test"
    lFindLen = Len(zFind)

    For Each rCell In Selection

       With rCell
          .Characters(Start:=InStr(.Value, zFind), Length:=lFindLen) _
          .Font.ColorIndex = 3  'Red -- Yellow too hard to read!
       End With

    Next rCell

End Sub
```